# Measurable function with periods is constant a.e.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

This is problem 7.4 from Rudin's real and complex analysis:

> Suppose $f$ is a real Lebesgue measurable function with periods $s$ and $t$ whose quotient $s/t$ is irrational. Prove that there is a constant $c$ such that $f(x)=c$ almost everywhere.

Rudin gives a hint: *Prove that for each $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ either the set $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} :f(x)>\lambda\}$ or its complement has measure $0$*.

I have shown the hint, which I think is the hard part. However, I cannot manage to use it to prove the problem.

What I am trying to do is the following: Assume $f$ is not constant almost everywhere. Then, for each $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$, the set $\{ x \in \mathbb{R} :f(x) \neq \lambda\}$ has positive measure. Now, I want to use the hint to prove that this is a contradiction but here is where I am stuck.

Any ideas on how should I proceed ?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider $inf\{x: f^{-1}((-\infty, x])$ has full measure $\}$

Comment: By full measure I just mean its complement has zero measure.  $\sup_xf^{-1}(x)$ is something nonsensical I wrote before I edited the comment.  Does it look different now?

Comment: @Timkinsella Thanks again Tim. So, if $E_\lambda = \{ x : f(x)>\lambda \}$, you are suggesting me to look at $\inf\{ \lambda : \mu(E_\lambda)=0\}$. I kind of see why one cares about that. However, for each $\lambda$, I only know that either  $\mu(E_\lambda)=0$ or $ \mu(\mathbb{R} \setminus E_\lambda)=0$, how this helps me to compute the infimum?

Comment: yes thats right

Comment: @Timkinsella My instinct tells me that this infimum has to be a real number (i.e. is not $-\infty$). Moreover, I think that if $F_\lambda = \{ x : f(x)<\lambda\}$ one could show that $\inf\{ \lambda : \mu(E_\lambda)=0\} = \sup\{ \lambda : \mu(F_\lambda)=0\}$. However, I really don´t see how to prove it !

Comment: I'm suggesting that you try to prove that this infimum is your $c$.

Comment: @Timkinsella Right! I guess I should not be trying to prove it by contradiction then. Thanks for the hint !

Comment: I would try to show that $\mu f^{-1}(c,\infty)= \mu f^{-1}(-\infty, c) =0$.  You may need to use "upper continuity" of measure for one of those.

Comment: You're welcome. Let me know if you get stuck.

Comment: @Timkinsella Dear Tim, I managed to prove it using your suggestion! Thanks again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may already have several solution by now. In any event, here is what I got.

---

Assuming that you prove the stament is Rudin's hint,
It is enough to consider the case where there is $\lambda$ such that $m(f>\lambda)=0$. Let $d:=\inf\{\lambda: m(f>\lambda)=0\}$ (otherwise, apply what you proved to $-f$ ).

1. If $d\in\mathbb{R}$, then $m(f>d)=0$ (an approximation argument by a sequence $\lambda_n\searrow d$ such that $m(f>\lambda_n)=0$ along with monotone convergence proves this claim). Furthermore, for any  $b<d$, $m(f>b)>0$ which means that $m(f\leq b)=0$ by what you proved. This shows that $f=d$ a.s.
2. If $d=-\infty$, the $f=-\infty$ a.s.

---

Would you care to share your solution of for the hint?

---

Comment: Hi Oliver! This was a while ago, but I remember I was able to finish using Tim's suggestion on the comments above. To prove Rudin's hint, I proved first that the set $P =\{ns+mt : n,m \in \Bbb{Z}\}$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}$. I then took a sequence $(p_n)$ in $P$ such that $p_n \to 0$ to prove that for each $\lambda \in \Bbb{R}$, the set $E_\lambda:=\{x \in \Bbb{R} : f(x)> \lambda \}$ has arbitrarily small periods. Finally, I invoked the result from Rudin’s Problem 7.3.  Hope this helps.

Comment: @AlonsoDelfín: I was talking about the hint. My solution goes along the lines of Tim's comment. I had used that argument before .... Could you please edit your previous comment to make it a little more readable. The LaTeX text is missing a "\$" somewhere

Comment: Should be readable by now.